# excel function that stores the current date and does not update

Tags: excel, date

I have used the excel function Now() to enter the current date. The problem is every time I open the excel workbook it changes the cell to the current date. I need it to remain the date I entered it in. I have also tried function Today() and it does the same thing.

Comment: you will need to either copy paste just the value or use a vba sub to set the date as a static value.  A formula is live and will continue to update.

Comment: Or use `Ctrl`+`;` to enter the current date as a value.